# Designed layout not displaying in the design view

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile-application

[image: android studio interface]

The designed layout not show in the display view. It show as the above image. So, I can't do any modifications without seeing the design. How to fix this issue?

[image]
I need to display the design view like this

Comment: I have had this issue before and could only fix it by closing and reopening Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

These steps can help to fix your problem:

1. Check your XML layout for any errors. If there are some errors in your layout, the preview may not be visible
2. Upgrade Gradle version: `File -> Project Structure -> Project`. Upgrate the gradle version there.
3. Try to change theme. It may help too:
   [image]
4. Delete .idea, .gradle folders.
5. `Build -> Clean Project`.
6. `File -> Invalidate caches and restart` (you may also needed to invalidate caches after step 2.